# Docker toolbox or docker CE - Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I have a Windows 10 running in the VirtualBox.
I want to install Docker to run in this Windows 10.

What should I install: Docker CE or Docker Toolbox?
I think to install Docker Toolbox make sense but I don't know if I will be able to install Docker CE as well.

Comment: Docker Toolbox is deprecated, so if you can install Docker CE go for it

Comment: Be careful, Docker for Windows forces you to use Hyper-V. If it's enabled, you'll not be able to use VirtualBox. Unless you run VirtualBox 6.x - as far as I know it's finally able to run on Windows with Hyper-V, though it still (?) has some issues.

Anyway, if you want to run just Windows Containers, you may download and use two Docker binaries: docker and dockerd. Add them to Path and set dockerd to run as a service): https://master.dockerproject.org/windows/x86_64/docker.zip

If you want to run also Linux Containers, install Docker CE and enable Hyper-V, but VB may have some issues.